# python win32 COM closing excel workbook

Tags: python, winapi, excel, com, win32com

I open several different workbooks (excel xlsx format) in COM, and mess with them. As the program progresses I wish to close one specific workbook but keep the rest open.

How do I close ONE workbook? (instead of the entire excel application)

```
xl = Dispatch("Excel.Application")
xl.Visible = False
try:
    output = xl.Workbooks.Open(workbookName)
    output2 = xl.Workbooks.Open(workbook2Name)
except com_error:
    print "you screwed up blahblahblah"
    exit()

#work on some stuff
#close output but keep output2 open
```

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The the Workbook COM object [has a Close() method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff838613.aspx). Basically, it should be something like:

```
xl = Dispatch('Excel.Application')
wb = xl.Workbooks.Open('New Workbook.xlsx')
# do some stuff
wb.Close(True) # save the workbook
```

---

The above was just a skeleton here's some code that works on my machine against Office 2010:

```
from win32com.client import Dispatch
xl = Dispatch('Excel.Application')
wb = xl.Workbooks.Add()
ws = wb.Worksheets.Add()
cell = ws.Cells(1)
cell.Value = 'Some text'
wb.Close(True, r'C:\Path\to\folder\Test.xlsx')
```

Of course, that creates a new xlsx file. But then I'm able to successfully open and modify the file in the same session as follows:

```
wb = xl.Workbooks.Open(r'C:\Path\to\folder\Test.xlsx')
ws = wb.Worksheets(1)
cell = ws.Cells(2)
cell.Value = 'Some more text'
wb.Close(True)
```

Don't know if any of that helps...

Comment: @RazorStorm: What version of Excel / Office are you using? See my slightly longer examples.

Comment: Weird... it works now. I guess I wrote it wrong when I tested it earlier or something.

Comment: Must first install package `pywin32` from https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32. For examples, of how to use, https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32/blob/master/pywin32_testall.py. Must use `import win32api` before running this script.

Comment: Notice that in case the workbook has "on save" event handlers, it is possible (in Excel Office 365) that `Close(True)` unintuitively manages to close the workbook before it's saved; in those cases `wb.Save(); wb.Close()` is safer.

Answer (score 10):

You can also try to use the following code:

```
excel = Dispatch("Excel.Application")
excel.Visible = False
workbook = excel.Workbooks.Open(fileName)

# with saving
excel.DisplayAlerts = False
if saveAs:
    excel.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs(fullFileNameToSave)
else:
    excel.ActiveWorkbook.Save()
excel.Quit()

#without saving

map(lambda book: book.Close(False), excel.Workbooks)
excel.Quit()
```

Answer (score 1):

This function closes any opened excel file

```
import os

def closeFile():

    try:
        os.system('TASKKILL /F /IM excel.exe')

    except Exception:
        print("KU")

closeFile()
```

Answer (score -2):

```
def setAutoFilter(self,ws,AmountToMatch):
        amounttopass = f"{AmountToMatch}"
        print("The Amount  of that month is  ::",amounttopass)
        ws.Range("B:G").AutoFilter(Field=6, Criteria1=amounttopass,VisibleDropDown=False)
        time.sleep(timeout)
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).