# From password-protected Excel file to pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

I can open a password-protected Excel file with this:

```
import sys
import win32com.client
xlApp = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
print "Excel library version:", xlApp.Version
filename, password = sys.argv[1:3]
xlwb = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(filename, Password=password)
# xlwb = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(filename)
xlws = xlwb.Sheets(1) # counts from 1, not from 0
print xlws.Name
print xlws.Cells(1, 1) # that's A1
```

I'm not sure though how to transfer the information to a pandas dataframe. Do I need to read cells one by one and all, or is there a convenient method for this to happen?

Comment: Does `xlws` have a `Row` and `RowCount` (or whatever they're called) - if so, then loop over the number of rows and build a list of lists... Then use `pandas.DataFrame` on that... (sorry - don't use windows - so can't give this a go myself)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming the starting cell is given as (StartRow, StartCol) and the ending cell is given as (EndRow, EndCol), I found the following worked for me:

```
# Get the content in the rectangular selection region
# content is a tuple of tuples
content = xlws.Range(xlws.Cells(StartRow, StartCol), xlws.Cells(EndRow, EndCol)).Value 

# Transfer content to pandas dataframe
dataframe = pandas.DataFrame(list(content))
```

Note: Excel Cell B5 is given as row 5, col 2 in win32com. Also, we need list(...) to convert from tuple of tuples to list of tuples, since there is no pandas.DataFrame constructor for a tuple of tuples.

Comment: You can also use letters for the range, for example: xlws.Range("A1:H100").Value.

Answer (score 17):

## Simple solution

```
import io
import pandas as pd
import msoffcrypto

passwd = 'xyz'

decrypted_workbook = io.BytesIO()
with open(path_to_your_file, 'rb') as file:
    office_file = msoffcrypto.OfficeFile(file)
    office_file.load_key(password=passwd)
    office_file.decrypt(decrypted_workbook)

df = pd.read_excel(decrypted_workbook, sheet_name='abc')
```

---

```
pip install --user msoffcrypto-tool
```

### Exporting all sheets of each excel from directories and sub-directories to seperate csv files

```
from glob import glob
PATH = "Active Cons data"

# Scaning all the excel files from directories and sub-directories
excel_files = [y for x in os.walk(PATH) for y in glob(os.path.join(x[0], '*.xlsx'))] 

for i in excel_files:
    print(str(i))
    decrypted_workbook = io.BytesIO()
    with open(i, 'rb') as file:
        office_file = msoffcrypto.OfficeFile(file)
        office_file.load_key(password=passwd)
        office_file.decrypt(decrypted_workbook)

    df = pd.read_excel(decrypted_workbook, sheet_name=None)
    sheets_count = len(df.keys())
    sheet_l = list(df.keys())  # list of sheet names
    print(sheet_l)
    for i in range(sheets_count):
        sheet = sheet_l[i]
        df = pd.read_excel(decrypted_workbook, sheet_name=sheet)
        new_file = f"D:\\all_csv\\{sheet}.csv"
        df.to_csv(new_file, index=False)
```

Comment: This is very helpful, though I'd recommend changing the variable `i` in the simple solution to something that indicates that it's the path to the file, `file_path` for example, as `i` is commonly used as an iterator. Took me a minute to figure out...

Answer (score 7):

from David Hamann's site (all credits go to him)
https://davidhamann.de/2018/02/21/read-password-protected-excel-files-into-pandas-dataframe/

Use xlwings, opening the file will first launch the Excel application so you can enter the password.

```
import pandas as pd
import xlwings as xw

PATH = '/Users/me/Desktop/xlwings_sample.xlsx'
wb = xw.Book(PATH)
sheet = wb.sheets['sample']

df = sheet['A1:C4'].options(pd.DataFrame, index=False, header=True).value
df
```

Comment: Looks like there's a `password` argument in `xw.Book()` (maybe this was added to the API since this answer). https://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/api.html?highlight=password#book

Answer (score 3):

Based on the suggestion provided by @ikeoddy, this should put the pieces together:

[How to open a password protected excel file using python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19450837/how-to-open-a-password-protected-excel-file-using-python)

```
# Import modules
import pandas as pd
import win32com.client
import os
import getpass

# Name file variables
file_path = r'your_file_path'
file_name = r'your_file_name.extension'

full_name = os.path.join(file_path, file_name)
# print(full_name)
```

[Getting command-line password input in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9202224/getting-command-line-password-input-in-python)

```
# You are prompted to provide the password to open the file
xl_app = win32com.client.Dispatch('Excel.Application')
pwd = getpass.getpass('Enter file password: ')
```

[Workbooks.Open Method (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.Workbooks.Open)

```
xl_wb = xl_app.Workbooks.Open(full_name, False, True, None, pwd)
xl_app.Visible = False
xl_sh = xl_wb.Worksheets('your_sheet_name')

# Get last_row
row_num = 0
cell_val = ''
while cell_val != None:
    row_num += 1
    cell_val = xl_sh.Cells(row_num, 1).Value
    # print(row_num, '|', cell_val, type(cell_val))
last_row = row_num - 1
# print(last_row)

# Get last_column
col_num = 0
cell_val = ''
while cell_val != None:
    col_num += 1
    cell_val = xl_sh.Cells(1, col_num).Value
    # print(col_num, '|', cell_val, type(cell_val))
last_col = col_num - 1
# print(last_col)
```

ikeoddy's answer:

```
content = xl_sh.Range(xl_sh.Cells(1, 1), xl_sh.Cells(last_row, last_col)).Value
# list(content)
df = pd.DataFrame(list(content[1:]), columns=content[0])
df.head()
```

[python win32 COM closing excel workbook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6337595/python-win32-com-closing-excel-workbook)

```
xl_wb.Close(False)
```

Comment: Instead of manually counting the number of rows and columns, simple use `xl_sh..UsedRange.Rows.Count` and `xl_sh.UsedRange.Columns.Count`

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you can save the encrypted file back to disk using the win32com API (which I realize might defeat the purpose) you could then immediately call the top-level pandas function `read_excel`. You'll need to install some combination of `xlrd` (for Excel 2003), `xlwt` (also for 2003), and `openpyxl` (for Excel 2007) first though. [Here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#excel-files) is the documentation for reading in Excel files. Currently pandas does not provide support for using the win32com API to read Excel files. You're welcome to [open up a GitHub issue](https://www.github.com/pydata/pandas/issues) if you'd like.

Comment: I can't test it anymore, as I currently don't work in an environment that enables me to do so. I will though mark this or any other answer as accepted if you give the example code and assure me that it works. :7)

Comment: I don't know how to use the win32com API so you'd have to figure that out yourself, but if you look at the documentation that I gave a link to, it gives instructions for doing exactly what you want. There's no need to replicate the example code here since you can just read it there.

Answer (score 2):

Adding to @Maurice answer to get all the cells in the sheet without having to specify the range

```
wb = xw.Book(PATH, password='somestring')
sheet = wb.sheets[0] #get first sheet

#sheet.used_range.address returns string of used range
df = sheet[sheet.used_range.address].options(pd.DataFrame, index=False, header=True).value
```

Comment: AttributeError: '<win32com.gen_py.Microsoft Excel 16.0 Object Library._Worksheet instance at 0x2501460928384>' object has no attribute 'used_range'

Comment: I recently got a similar error but I have subsequently had to upgrade to Office 365 so that may be my problem. The code here was using Office 2016.

Comment: Maybe, I'm using Office 365 too.