# read encrypted excel with pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas, encryption

I am scanning data through encrypted excel files with python. I would like to read the file content without opening excel. Here is my code. I usually use pandas to read files but pandas.read_excel do not allows to add password.

```
from xlrd import *
import win32com.client
import csv
import sys

xlApp = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
xlwb = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(path1+file_name, Password='password')
```

Thank you

Comment: This should get you started: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36850716/from-password-protected-excel-file-to-python-object

Answer (score 1):

Check and upvote if below lines help......

```
from xlrd import *
import win32com.client
import csv
import sys
import pandas as pd
from tempfile import NamedTemporaryFile

xlApp = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
filename,password = r'fullpath','password'

# Note this line from the question posted
xlwb = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(filename, False, True, None, password)

xlws = xlwb.Sheets(1) # index is from 1
print (xlws.Name)
print (xlws.Cells(1, 1)) # if you need cell values

f = NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False, suffix='.csv')
f.close()
os.unlink(f.name)  

xlCSVWindows = 0x17  # CSV file format, from enum XlFileFormat
xlwb.SaveAs(Filename=f.name, FileFormat=xlCSVWindows) # Save as CSV
df = pd.read_csv(f.name)  
print(df.head())
df.to_csv('myoutput.csv',index=False)
```