# Reading excel file in pandas protected with password

Tags: excel, pandas, passwords

I having a lot of trouble opening a "xlsx" workbook that is password protected. I want to read the file through pandas.

```
pd.read_excel(filepath, sheet_name)
```

I got the following error
XLRDError: Can't find workbook in OLE2 compound document

I know the password I went to the review tab to unprotect the workbook but it can't be done. So is there a way to read the xlsx file into pandas with the secure password?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [From password-protected Excel file to pandas DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15285068/from-password-protected-excel-file-to-pandas-dataframe)