# Reading password protected Excel

Tags: excel, julia

I am currently using XLSX library to read an Excel sheet as follows.

```
using DataFrames
using XLSX

df = DataFrame(XLSX.readtable(excel_path, "sheet_name")...)
```

Now, I would like to read a password-protected Excel file, is there any way to do this?
Currently in Python, I use [the following solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15285068/from-password-protected-excel-file-to-pandas-dataframe). Is there any equivalent way in Julia, or is it just not doable at this stage?

```py
import io
import pandas as pd
import msoffcrypto

passwd = 'xyz'

decrypted_workbook = io.BytesIO()
with open(path_to_your_file, 'rb') as file:
    office_file = msoffcrypto.OfficeFile(file)
    office_file.load_key(password=passwd)
    office_file.decrypt(decrypted_workbook)

df = pd.read_excel(decrypted_workbook, sheet_name='abc')
```

Comment: I would load `msoffcrypto` via `PythonCall.jl`, decrypt the file using Python's API, save it a a temporary file and than load the decrypted temporary file with `XLXS.jl`. Not exactly perfect but this should be quite robust and work well in production.