# How to Quit / terminate / exit a particular Excel File in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, openpyxl, win32com

I want to close/quit/terminate a particular excel file only. Based on  my script, it closes all open/active excel files. My intention is to force close a particular file only. How to resolve it?

For Example, In my case I open, more than 3 excel files in active mode(open), Now I Run the script, to append data in a particular excel file (**example.xlxs**).It's in open mode, so raises an **error code 13, permission error**. so my necessity to forcibly close that particular file programmatically.  But, it closes all open excel files.

Googleing so many things including xlwings.quit() . xlwings.quit() also closed all open/active excel files.

please suggest a better way to resolve it.

```
import sys
import os
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget,QApplication,QMessageBox,QSizePolicy
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon

from openpyxl import load_workbook
from win32com.client import Dispatch

my_filename = r'd:\me\openpyxl\example.xlsx'
companies = [['name1','address1','tel1','web1'], ['name2','address2','tel2','web2']]

class Force_to_close_open_excel_files(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(). __init__()
        self.show_errormsg = "show"
        self.append_data()

    def append_data(self):
        try:
            active_workbook = load_workbook(filename=my_filename)
            active_work_sheet = active_workbook.active
            active_workbook.save(filename=my_filename)

            for info in companies:
                active_work_sheet.append(info)
            print("data Added Sucessfully")
            active_workbook.save(filename=my_filename)

        except Exception as e:
            if self.show_errormsg == 'show':
                self.handle_error(e)
            else:
                pass

    def handle_error(self, error):
        exc_type, exc_value, exc_traceback = sys.exc_info()
        filenamewithpath = exc_traceback.tb_frame.f_code.co_filename
        head, tail = os.path.split((filenamewithpath))
        lineno = exc_traceback.tb_lineno
        name = exc_traceback.tb_frame.f_code.co_name
        type = exc_type.__name__
        message = exc_value
        error_no = ([x[0] for x in [message.args]])

        nl = '\n'
        kk = f'File Name : {tail[:-3]}{nl}' \
             f'Line No. : {lineno}{nl}' \
             f'Type : {type}{nl}' \
             f'Error Code : {error_no[0]}{nl}'\
             f'Name : {name}{nl}'

        self.msg = QMessageBox()
        self.msg.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.MinimumExpanding,QSizePolicy.MinimumExpanding)
        self.msg.setWindowTitle("  Error/Bugs Information")
        self.msg.setWindowIcon(QIcon('icon\close006.png'))
        self.msg.setText(f'{type} - Line No {lineno}')
        self.msg.setIcon(QMessageBox.Information)
        self.msg.setStandardButtons(QMessageBox.Ok)
        self.msg.addButton(QMessageBox.Close)
        self.btn_focestop = self.msg.button(QMessageBox.Close)
        self.btn_focestop.setText("Force to Close - Excel Files")
        self.msg.setDefaultButton(QMessageBox.Ok)
        self.msg.setInformativeText("")
        self.msg.setDetailedText(kk)
        self.msg.show()
        self.msg.exec_()

        if self.msg.clickedButton() ==  self.btn_focestop:
            excel = Dispatch("Excel.Application")
            excel.Visible = False
            workbook = excel.Workbooks.Open(my_filename)
            map(lambda book: book.Close(False), excel.Workbooks)
            excel.Quit()
            self.append_data()

def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Force_to_close_open_excel_files()
    # ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6337595/python-win32-com-closing-excel-workbook) Question and [ig0774](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/6338030/edit)  solution, I will try the following, and its works for me

```
 if self.msg.clickedButton() ==  self.btn_focestop:
        excel = Dispatch("Excel.Application")
        # excel.Visible = False
        workbook = excel.Workbooks.Open(my_filename)
        # map(lambda book: book.Close(False), excel.Workbooks)
        # excel.Quit()
        workbook.Close(True)
```